# Iterações em uma lista de tupla

Tags: python, lista, append, tupla

Boa tarde,

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Tenho uma lista de tupla chamada lista_cromossomos, com 10 posições.

Quero abrir uma posição nova no final dela (11º posição), onde ela será inicialmente igual a primeira.
Para isso usei

```
lista_cromossomos.append.(lista_cromossomos[0])
```

Resultado:

[[1, 0, 0, 0], .., [1, 0, 0, 0]]    -> 11 termos, onde o primeiro e o último são iguais

Quero múltiplicar apenas os componentes do último termo por 7 para ficar [7, 0, 0, 0], logo o esperado é:

Resultado esperado:

[[1, 0, 0, 0], .., [7, 0, 0, 0]]

Para isso usei:

```
 for y in range(0, len(lista_cromossomos[10])):
        lista_cromossomos[10][y] = lista_cromossomos[10][y] * 7
```

Acontece que ao invés de múltiplicar apenas a última tupla, ele múltiplica a última e a primeira.

Resultado do código:

[[7, 0, 0, 0], .., [7, 0, 0, 0]]    -

O que tem de errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro de tudo você deve saber que quando você cria uma lista ou qualquer outro objeto, você não atribui à variável o objeto em si e sim um endereço de memória do objeto que está guardado dentro da sua memória RAM.

Logo quando criamos um código desse tipo:

```
lista1 = [1,0,0,0]
lista2 = lista1
```

Nós não estamos criando um novo objeto de `list()` para a `lista2`, nós apenas passamos o endereço de memória da `lista1`. Ou seja, tanto `lista1` como `lista2` apontam para o mesmo objeto na memória.

É exatamente por esse motivo que quando você altera os valores da lista da posição final, os valores da lista da primeira posição também são alterados.

E como resolvemos o problema ? Basta criar um novo objeto usando uma dessas duas formas:

```
# O método copy() retorna um novo objeto com os mesmos valores.
lista_cromossomos.append(lista_cromossomos[0].copy()) 

# Abaixo nós obtemos uma nova lista através de slice.
lista_cromossomos.append(lista_cromossomos[0][:])
```

Comment: Muito bom, resolveu parcialmente.
No caso completo se trata de uma classe, onde o primeito atributo é esse "cromossomos", e o segundo é um número float.
Quando uso isso no float aparece o seguinte erro:
'float' object has no attribute 'copy'

Fiz assim:

```
classe[10].cromossomo =classe[0].cromossomo.copy        -> Funciona
classe[10].numero = classe[x].numero.copy                        -> Não funciona
```

Sabe o por que?

Comment: O método `copy()` só existe para os objetos de `list()`, `dict()` e `set()` (talvez existam para outros objetos). O que eu falei de "endereços de memória" não é aplicado para valores de tipos primitivos, então diferentemente do exemplo que mostrei na resposta, ao fazer o código `inteiro2 = inteiro1`, um novo valor seria criado e atribuído à variável. Por isso, não há motivo de se ter um método `copy()` para tipos primitivos.

Answer (score 0):

Codigo para fazer o que voce quer:

```
#declarar variaveis
tuplo = (1,0,0,0)
lista_de_10tuplos = []

#criar lista de 10 tuplos
for i in range(0,10):
    lista_de_10tuplos += [tuplo,]
    
print (lista_de_10tuplos)

#adicionar um tuplo
lista_de11_tuplos = lista_de_10tuplos + [tuplo,]

#criar tuplo modificado
tuplo_modificado = (tuplo[0]*7, tuplo[1], tuplo[2], tuplo[3])
#nota: seria mais simples ecrever tuplo_modificado = (7,0,0,0) mas assim 
#o codigo nao faria uma multiplicacao

#substituir ultimo tuplo por tuplo modificado
lista_de11_tuplos[10]=tuplo_modificado

print (lista_de11_tuplos)
```

Retorno que obtive dos prints:

> [(1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0)]
>
> [(1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0), (7, 0, 0, 0)]